# Is PostgreSQL 9.2 autovacuum sufficient for a busy table?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, vacuum

I have one table on a PostgreSQL 9.2/PostGIS 2.0.1 database:

```
CREATE TABLE ch02.markers  
(
  ff_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  col1 boolean,
  col2 smallint,
  created_at timestamp,
  lat double precision,
  lon double precision,
  geog geography(POINT,4326)
);

CREATE INDEX idx_markers_geog ON ch02.markers USING gist(geog);
```

This table is having records, probably thousands but potentially tens of thousands per hour, inserted and deleted 24/7.

I am wondering if the default autovacuum settings will sufficiently manage the table?

Otherwise I presume I write a SP function that is called by cron. However, what should I use? VACUUM ANALYZE? I am wary of using any anything that locks the table (CLUSTER, REINDEX). Do these even work for an index on a geography point column?

I am not used to such active tables and I am completely new to Postgres, so I have absolutely no feel for this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You may get better answers at dba.SE.

Comment: We do about 5000 inserts per second on PostgreSQL 9.1 and it works.

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter Thanks - I didn't even realise there was such a thing. I shall direct my db questions there from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you fiddle with cron jobs and other curiosities you can *adjust* the autovacuum default settings just inside PostgreSQL. This can be done globally or individually for each table.

Comment: Without some basic configuration, it's too slow anyway.

Comment: @FrankHeikens: Maybe, but Polly asked specifically about the "default configuration". Of course this might no be what he _wanted_ to ask but who knows that...

Comment: @FrankHeikens: You do not mention deletes which I understand are more demanding upon VACUUM. But, I take from your responses that I should be fine with autovacuum as long as I tune it properly. Is that correct?

Comment: @A.H.: Ok I will go and read about the autovacuum settings.

Comment: @Polly: Yes, that is correct. Tune your database and your SQL to get the best performance for your specific situation. No default configuration can get the max performance out of any workload. And it's not just auto vacuum that needs some tuning, other settings as well. The default configuration is just good enough to get the database started.

Comment: @FrankHeikens: Great, thanks very much. I will read about autovacuum settings. I have an index on the geog point column. Can you point me in the direction of what other settings I should be looking at?